# Date Scanner in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr

I want to scan date from any product and display it in my database. Every where I found Barcode scanners and Qr scanners.How can I scan date in iOS. Is there any possible way to do this..?

Comment: Asking for libraries is offtopic for stackoverflow, but just to give you little kick in the right direction don't look for date scanner but for OCR.

Comment: you may wanna try tesseract-ocr

Comment: Note that dates can have very different formats from one country to another, and without context, it may be difficult to guess what format it is. For instance, is 01/02/03 February 1st, 2003 (as it would be in France or the UK for instance) or January 2nd, 2003 (as it would be in the US)?

Comment: Also note that barcodes and QR codes are made to be machine readable, so they are relatively easy to detect and decode, and they include error detection or even error correction. Regular text doesn't have that, so it's a lot more CPU-intensive, you may have decoding errors as well as false positives.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you can try Airtable or Orca Scan.

Airtable has field you can add that will auto record the date/time when you capture the barcode. Free plan is 1200 rows per database.

Orca Scan for iOS can also do this. Free is 1 user 100 rows.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this (free) product is exactly what you need: [Real-Time Recognition SDK](http://rtrsdk.com).

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.